# Why is my player jumping moving out of the corner?

Tags: python, pygame

Sorry if this is a duplicate question, also I would like to apologize for the horrible structure of my code in advance. I'm programming just for a hobby and started this program just for the random map to use in a different game I was working on. It's horrible I know I have no classes, not even 1 function. I really was just exploring how to make a random map, and it turned into how do I scroll this map, how do I make it fit the screen, then what to do when I hit the sides... What I am really stuck on before I turn this into what I really want is the corners. I can move my player all around but if I go left into a side then up into a corner, I end up back in the middle of the screen rather than scrolling along in the center-top of the screen. I'd like to thank you in advance for the help here is the code.

```
import random
import pygame

#Make the random map------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#Set constants for the height and width of the tiles on the map
TILE_H = 60
TILE_W = 60

tree_tile = pygame.image.load('forrest.jpg')
tree_tile = pygame.transform.scale(tree_tile,(TILE_W,TILE_H))
grass_tile = pygame.image.load('grass.jpg')
grass_tile = pygame.transform.scale(grass_tile,(TILE_W,TILE_H))
#Create surface tiles to populate the map
#grass_tile = pygame.Surface((TILE_W,TILE_H))
water_tile = pygame.Surface((TILE_W,TILE_H))
#tree_tile = pygame.Surface((TILE_W,TILE_H))
sand_tile = pygame.Surface((TILE_W,TILE_H))
hill_tile = pygame.Surface((TILE_W,TILE_H))

#Pick colors for the tiles
#grass_tile.fill((0,255,0))
water_tile.fill((0,0,255))
#tree_tile.fill((30,180,0))
sand_tile.fill((255,255,10))
hill_tile.fill((150,80,10))


#Randomly pick the order of the tiles in rows, and columns. Then store in the list tile_list.
tile_list = []
def map_row():
    row = []
    for i in range(0,256):
        x = random.randint(1,100)
        if 0 < x < 11:
            tile = water_tile
        elif 10 < x < 21:
            tile = hill_tile
        elif 20 < x < 36:
            tile = sand_tile
        elif 35 < x < 61:
            tile = tree_tile
        elif 60 < x < 101:
            tile = grass_tile
        else:
            print('out of range')

        row.append(tile)

    tile_list.append(row)

def map_column():
    for i in range(0,256):
        map_row()

map_column()
#End of random map maker-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#Initiate pygame, set up the screen and clock for FPS
pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((0,0), pygame.FULLSCREEN)
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

#Set up constants for screen height and width
SCREEN_H = screen.get_height()
SCREEN_W = screen.get_width()

#Make a surface for the whole map and blit the tiles to it
map_surface = pygame.Surface(( len(tile_list[0])*TILE_W, len(tile_list)*TILE_H))

for y,row in enumerate(tile_list):
    for x,tile_surface in enumerate(row):
        map_surface.blit(tile_surface,(x*TILE_W,y*TILE_H))

#find a random starting position for the map on the screen then blit the screen to that position
map_posX = random.randrange((-(TILE_W * len(tile_list))+SCREEN_W),0,TILE_W)
map_posY = random.randrange((-(TILE_H * len(tile_list))+SCREEN_H),0,TILE_H)
screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
pygame.display.update()

#Make a player surface the same size of the screen
player = pygame.Surface((TILE_H,TILE_W))
player.fill((0,0,0))

edge_t = False
edge_b = False
edge_l = False
edge_r = False
#Main game loop------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
while True:

     # get the rect for the map and screen for use in calculations   
    map_rect = map_surface.get_rect()
    screen_rect = screen.get_rect()
    if edge_t == False and edge_b == False and edge_l == False and edge_r == False:
        player_rect = player.get_rect()


    #If they close the window quit out of pygame
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()

    #Assign stuff to keys, like if up is pressed move up   
    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
        #Move the map up if not at top and player not at the bottom
        if map_posY < -TILE_H and edge_b == False:
            map_posY += TILE_H
            screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
            edge_t = False
        elif map_rect.contains(player_rect):
            #Figure out where the player is at when they hit the top
            #Unless they are already on an edge
            if edge_t == False and edge_b == False and edge_l == False and edge_r == False:
                player_rect.bottom = (adjust_x+SCREEN_H/2)+1
                player_rect.left = (adjust_y+SCREEN_W/2)-1
                screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                player_tile_list_posY -= 1
                edge_t = True #Toggle edge_t

            #Move the player while not centered
            elif edge_t  or edge_b  or edge_l  or edge_r :
                #Don't let it move off the map
                if player_rect.top > TILE_H:
                    player_rect = player_rect.move(0,-TILE_H)
                    screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                    player_tile_list_posY -= 1

                #If leaving bottom edge turn edge_b off
                if edge_b  and player_rect.bottom < ((SCREEN_H/2)+TILE_H):
                    edge_b = False


    elif keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
        if map_posY > (-(TILE_H * len(tile_list))+SCREEN_H+TILE_H) and edge_t == False:
            map_posY -= TILE_H
            screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
            edge_b = False

        elif map_rect.contains(player_rect):
            #Figure out where the player is at when they hit the bottom
            #Unless they are already on an edge
            if edge_b == False and edge_t == False and edge_l == False and edge_r == False:
                player_rect.bottom = (adjust_x+SCREEN_H/2)+1
                player_rect.left = (adjust_y+SCREEN_W/2)-1
                screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                player_tile_list_posY += 1
                edge_b = True #Toggle edge_d

            #Move the player while not centered
            elif edge_b  or edge_t  or edge_l  or edge_r :
                if player_rect.bottom <= SCREEN_H-TILE_H:
                    player_rect = player_rect.move(0,TILE_H)
                    screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                    player_tile_list_posY += 1
            #If leaving top edge turn edge_t off
            if edge_t  and player_rect.bottom >= SCREEN_H/2:
                    edge_t = False


    elif keys[pygame.K_LEFT]:
        if map_posX < -TILE_W and edge_r == False:
            map_posX += TILE_W
            screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
            edge_l = False
        elif map_rect.contains(player_rect):
            #Figure out where the player is at when they hit the left
            #Unless they are already on an edge
            if edge_t == False and edge_b == False and edge_l == False and edge_r == False:
                player_rect.top = (adjust_x+SCREEN_H/2)+1
                player_rect.left = (adjust_y+SCREEN_W/2)-1
                screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                player_tile_list_posY -= 1
                edge_l = True #Toggle edge_l

            #Move the player while not centered
            elif edge_l  or edge_r  or edge_b  or edge_t :
                #Don't let it move off the map
                if player_rect.left > TILE_W:
                    player_rect = player_rect.move(-TILE_W,0)
                    screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                    player_tile_list_posX -= 1

                #If leaving right edge turn edge_r off
                if edge_r  and player_rect.right < ((SCREEN_W/2)+TILE_W):
                    edge_r = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_RIGHT]:
        if map_posX > (-(TILE_W * len(tile_list[0]))+SCREEN_W+TILE_W) and edge_l == False:
            map_posX -= TILE_W
            screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
            edge_r = False
        elif map_rect.contains(player_rect):
            #Figure out where the player is at when they hit the right
            #Unless they are already on an edge
            if edge_t == False and edge_b == False and edge_l == False and edge_r == False:
                player_rect.top = (adjust_x+SCREEN_H/2)+1
                player_rect.left = (adjust_y+SCREEN_W/2)-1
                screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                player_tile_list_posX -= 1
                edge_r = True #Toggle edge_r

            #Move the player while not centered
            elif edge_l  or edge_r  or edge_b  or edge_t :
                #Don't let it move off the map
                if player_rect.right <= SCREEN_W - TILE_W:
                    player_rect = player_rect.move(TILE_W,0)
                    screen.blit(map_surface,(map_posX,map_posY))
                    player_tile_list_posX -= 1

                #If leaving left edge turn edge_l off
                if edge_l  and player_rect.left > ((SCREEN_W/2)+TILE_W):
                    edge_l = False

    elif keys[pygame.K_ESCAPE]:
        pygame.quit()
    elif keys[pygame.K_RETURN]:
        print(edge_t)
        print(edge_l)

        if tile_list[player_tile_list_posY][player_tile_list_posX] == water_tile:
            player.fill((100,0,0))
        if tile_list[player_tile_list_posY][player_tile_list_posX] == grass_tile:
            print('Grass')
        if tile_list[player_tile_list_posY][player_tile_list_posX] == hill_tile:
            print('Hill')
        if tile_list[player_tile_list_posY][player_tile_list_posX] == sand_tile:
            print('Sand')
        if tile_list[player_tile_list_posY][player_tile_list_posX] == tree_tile:
            print('Tree')

    #Blit the player to the center of the screen and alligned with the tiles
    #If your not at the edge of the map
    if edge_t == False and edge_b == False and edge_l == False and edge_r == False:
        adjust_x = ((SCREEN_W/2)%TILE_W)-TILE_W
        adjust_y = ((SCREEN_H/2)%TILE_H)-TILE_H

        #Figure out what kind of tile they are standing on
        player_tile_list_posX = int(-(map_posX-((SCREEN_W+adjust_x)/2))/TILE_W)
        player_tile_list_posY = int(-(map_posY-((SCREEN_H+adjust_y)/2))/TILE_H)

        screen.blit(player, (adjust_x+SCREEN_W/2,adjust_y+SCREEN_H/2))


    if edge_t  or edge_b or edge_l  or edge_r :
        screen.blit(player,player_rect)

    #Update the display and check that the program is running at 20 FPS
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(20)
```

Comment: Have you tried to print the involved variables to the command-line console in real-time? Logging the values of involved variables is a good way to find unexpected behaviour in the algorythm and figuring out why isn't working like it is supposed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry again about how messy this program was written, I was more playing around with pygame trying to learn how to use it than anything. I've been busy the last couple of days and as soon as I looked at this again the answer smacked me in the face. I intentionally had made it so the player wouldn't recenter if they were already on the top or bottom, but this is the same code block where I changed the boolean for edge_x. So all I had to do was go back and add an if statement to make sure it changed to true if it was already on a different edge.